# Incorrect use of parentDataWidget in Flutter when loading json data

Tags: flutter, dart

Why it tells me that I am making an incorrect use of ParentDataWidget? Am I loading my json data properly? my goal is to put my json data into a ListView with a searchbar. Is it correct the structure at the moment of loading my data? Will it work when implementing my searchbar? I have tried other implementations with FutureBuilder but did not work

Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/assets/files/myfiles.json" (404)

```
class MainPage3 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<MainPage3> {
  List _items = [];
  List _meanings = [];
  List _examples = [];

  // Fetch content from the json file
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/files/myfiles.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      _items = data["VERB"];
      _meanings = data['MEANING'];
      _examples = data['EXAMPLE'];
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Kindacode.com',
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Load Data'),
              onPressed: readJson,
            ),

            // Display the data loaded from sample.json
            _items.length > 0
                ? Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Text(_items[index]["VERB"]),
                            title: Text(_meanings[index]["MEANING"]),
                            subtitle: Text(_examples[index]["EXAMPLE"]),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : Container()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My json data is like this:

```
{"VERB": "ASK  OUT", "MEANING": "To invite on a date", "EXAMPLE": "Martin invited Carol out to dinner on Sunday"},
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Expanded` widget above the `ListView.builder` and you'd be good to go. Why? `ListView` automatically takes up all the space that's available just like what an `Expanded` widget does, so removing it solves it. Also make sure you set `shrinkWrap` as true.

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  ...
```